# Visual Studio Community 2015 not installing - Fatal Error during installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried installing **Visual Studio Community 2015** on my Windows 10 Single Language OS via `Web download method` to create only **Windows Desktop apps with Visual Basic/C++/C#**.

I selected the `Default` option, it downloaded **~ 1 GB data (I'm on a capped connection of 8 GB/month, this is a lot for me).** and then it got stuck here -

[image: Pic 1]
**Continuation of image -**
[image]

It asked me to restart and run the tool again but it showed me the same error.

**My System Specs -**

- Windows 10 Single Language OS
- 2.2 GHz Intel i5
- 8 GB RAM

**PS -** How much internet does it takes to download the core features of Visual Studio Community 2015, as I said I am on a capped connection and won't try to download VS if the core features are greater than **4 GBs**.

Comment: On this window with errors you have references to  **log file** with more concrete description of error, please add info from this files to your question. And if you have such limited connection may be you should consider downloading image for offline installation, then you will be able to try installing many times until success. Even better if you will download it from some unlimited connection and then move on your computer.

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: go to a friend which has unlimited internet access,  downlaad the complete ISO which includes the Update 1: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49988 and install VS2015 from this ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer -

1) Delete ALL Visual C++ Redistributables and Visual Studio.

2) Go to Regedit and delete all registries related to Visual Studio.

3) Install only Visual C++ 2015 x64 and x86 Redistributables, then install Visual Studio.